# Sending Image Files back to the Browser

Tags: java, spring, servlets, grails, grails-2.0

My app has jpg image files that are displayed on my website.

in my GSP I do:

```
<img class="itemThumImage border-radius-top-3px" src="${createLink(controller:'item', action:'getImage', id:item.id)}" />
```

my getImage action of my ItemConroller is:

```
def getImage() {
   def item = Item.get(params.id)
   def file = new File(grailsApplication.parentContext.servletContext.getRealPath(item.id))

   response.setContentType("image/jpeg")
   response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=\"${item.id}.jpg\"")
   response.setContentLength(fileBytes.size())
   response.outputStream << file.readBytes()
   response.outputStream.close()
}
```

Is this a good way of sending the image back to the browser? I think that the image is loaded into heap. Can I accelerate this process somehow? Do I need `close()` at the last line or is it `flush()` or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's good for development/testing (but don't forget to `return null` after closing response).

But *never* do this on production system. You need a frontend server in front of your Tomcat, like Nginx or Apache HTTPD server.

I recommend Nginx. For Nginx you could use following configuration to serve this files:

```
location /item/getImage/ {
    alias /path/to/directory/with/images;
}

location / {
    //proxy to your Tomcat instance
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080; 
}
```

Comment: Why can't I do that on production with Tomcat?

Comment: because tomcat few 1000s times slower in serving static files